# debugging purposes, Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values

Tags: html, coldfusion

I still new in this course. can anyone help me with Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values?

here is the code:

```
<td name="" style="text-align: center;" width="130px">
                  <cfoutput>
                  <cfquery name="str1" datasource="abcd">
                    SELECT Verifyby
                    FROM str
                  </cfquery>


                      <form action="" method="post">
                      <cfquery datasource="abcd" name="sign">
                       SELECT Sign
                       FROM sign
                      </cfquery>
                      </form>

                    <cfset str1.Verifyby = '#Sign#'>
                    <cfset #Verifyby# = str1.Verifyby>

                    <cfif #Verifyby# eq ''>                     
                        <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="#Sign#" onclick="submit()">
                    <cfelse>
                      <p>#Verifyby#</p>
                    </cfif>
                  </cfoutput>
                </td>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: TBH, I think you'll need to take a bit more time about basic `html` and how `<form>` works. Also how we can use it with ColdFusion. Then try to understand how the pound (`#`) symbols work. That would be a good place to start. You're getting error here `value="#Sign#"`, because you are trying to display a query variable `sign` as string in here.

Comment: In addition, what are `str` and `signM`? It's possible the queries could use a JOIN, but .. hard to say without knowing more about the 2 tables and the relationship between them.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Your code just needs a little bit of refining

**Issue:**

The reason why you are getting an error, is because you are trying to read the value of an entire query into a 'simple value', in this case, a string:

```
<cfset str1.Verifyby = '#Sign#'>
```

I would also reorganise parts of your code so that all the business logic [queries, in this case] is above the HTML. And I would place the first branch of the conditional clause around the:

```
<form>
```

Its just easier to read and try not to use the '#' symbol, unneccessarily.

I also tend to use:

```
Len(Trim(variables.someVariable))
```

When testing for an empty string, in case, an unwanted space is present, unless you need to include empty spaces, in your equality test.

Also, remember to scope your variables. So:

```
<cfset verifyby = qStr1.Verifyby>
```

Should be:

```
<cfset variables.verifyby = qStr1.Verifyby>
```

Because, otherwise, Coldfusion has to use a precedence routine to determine what scope the variable might be in, which takes extra time.

However, as **Ageax** has pointed out, its probably best just to use the query column references directly here.

So, here is the solution:

```
<cfquery name="str1" datasource="DHRMS">
  SELECT Verifyby
  FROM str
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="DHRMS" name="sign">
  SELECT Sign
  FROM signM
</cfquery>

<td style="text-align: center;" width="130px">

  <cfoutput>

    <cfif NOT Len(Trim(qStr1.Verifyby))>
      <form action="save_HOD-staff" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="#qSign.Sign#" onclick="submit()">
      </form>
    <cfelse>
      <p>#qStr1.Verifyby#</p>
    </cfif>

  </cfoutput>

</td>
```

Comment: True, though in most cases the extra time is negligible. IMO, the primary reason for scoping is eliminating ambiguity.  CF allows the same variable name to be declared in multiple scopes. It doesn't always "guess" correctly when it applies the precedence rules. Scoping ensures you get the variable you expected. I realize it's just for illustration... but, creating a copy of `qStr1.Verifyby` doesn't serve any purpose ;-). Just use the variable directly in the output.  (Also, it's not clear whether the two queries contain multiple records, which might also change the code).

Comment: Yes. You are correct about scoping, but I thought for the OP, a new comer, this might be a good general tip.

Comment: Scoping is definitely a good tip!  Just mentioning another one, as new users often create extra variables/copies because they don't realize they can just use the original variable directly.

Comment: @Ageax Actually, now, the solution does require placeholders, because, I noticed that the queries require 'recordcount' testing. This will avoid the page from throwing an error, if eiither table is empty. I realise this is an edge case, but I feel it is a valid scenario.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I'm not convinced of that ;-) A) Because `qSign.Sign` would still evaluate to an empty string, even if the query contained 0 records and B) I suspect they're using the queries incorrectly.  Seems very unlikely both queries would return only 1 record (since neither has a WHERE clause), yet the cfoutput doesn't use a query loop to iterate through all records. So I suspect their current code isn't correct anyway. Nor representative of their real goal. That is why I asked about the tables and their relationships in the comments below the question.

Comment: @Ageax Yes. You are correct about using direct query column references. It must be the heat;) I have ammended my answer to reflect this...

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset str1.Verifyby = '#Sign#'> 
<cfset #Verifyby# = str1.Verifyby>
```

Should Read:

```
<cfset str1.Verifyby = Sign.sign />
<cfset Verifyby = str1.Verifyby />
```

Your wrapping you **query result object** in a string and then trying to output it as a string, which is not legal because it is a *complex object*. Presuming you want the value of the queried column you need to reference the column within the query result.

If you want to prove that it is a complex object add this code just below the cfquery:

```
<cfdump var='#sign#' abort='true'/>
```

That said, there is a lot more wrong with this code. The code below should run; however that doesn't mean is will do what you intend.

```
<td style="text-align: center;" width="130px">
  <cfoutput>
    <!--- Get the current verifyBy value, but not using? --->
    <cfquery name="currentVerifyBy" datasource="DHRMS">
      SELECT Verifyby
      FROM str
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="getSign" datasource="DHRMS">
      SELECT Sign
      FROM signM
    </cfquery>

    <cfset Verifyby = getSign.sign />

    <cfif Verifyby eq ''>
      <form action="save_HOD-staff" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="#getSign.Sign#" onclick="submit()">
      </form>
    <cfelse>
      <p>#Verifyby#</p>
    </cfif>
  </cfoutput>
</td>
```